# For a nest button tag inside there are other tags like section, label, paragraph. Screen reader narrating all the tags as buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have an accessibility bug that is Users who rely on screen readers are getting impacted as NVDA is narrating information multiple times for multiple buttons present in the page, while navigating using down arrow key.
There is a button tag inside there is other tags. But screen reader reading other tags as button, and I need to fix that.

Expecting that Screen reader show narrate only Button one time only not to repeat again with other tags.

```html
<button class="btn" [ngClass]="{'border-color-Red': answer?.AnswerId == 1,
  'border-color-Orange': answer?.AnswerId == 2,
  'border-color-Yellow': answer?.AnswerId == 3,
  'border-color-LightGreen': answer?.AnswerId == 4, 
  'border-color-Green': answer?.AnswerId == 5}" (click)="selectAnswer(answer)">
  <section class="d-flex">
    <section class="header" [ngClass]="{'color-Red': assesment?.SelectedAnswerId == 1 && answer?.AnswerId == 1, 
      'color-Orange': assesment?.SelectedAnswerId == 2 && answer?.AnswerId == 2,
      'color-Yellow': assesment?.SelectedAnswerId == 3 && answer?.AnswerId == 3,
      'color-LightGreen': assesment?.SelectedAnswerId == 4  && answer?.AnswerId == 4, 
      'color-Green': assesment?.SelectedAnswerId == 5 && answer?.AnswerId == 5,
      'color-pink': answer?.AnswerId == 1,
      'color-light-orange':answer?.AnswerId == 2,
      'color-light-yellow':answer?.AnswerId == 3,
      'color-light-yellowgreen':answer?.AnswerId == 4,
      'color-green-light':answer?.AnswerId == 5}">
      <h6 class="font-caption-alt">{{answer.AnswerId}} = {{answer.Answer}}</h6>
    </section>
    <section class="body">
      <p>{{answer.AnswerDesciption}}</p>
    </section>
    <section class="footer">
      <label class="font-caption">
        <input type="radio" id="answer-{{assesment?.Id}}-select-{{answer.Id}}"
          [attr.aria-label]="isSelectedAnswer(assesment, answer?.AnswerId)?'Selected Radio':'Not Selected Radio'"
          name="{{assesment?.Id}}-select" (click)="selectAnswer(assesment,answer)"
          [checked]="isSelectedAnswer(assesment, answer?.AnswerId)" tabindex="0" />
        <label for="answer-{{assesment?.Id}}-select-{{answer.Id}}"></label>
        Select
      </label>
    </section>
  </section>
</button>
```

Comment: If you're worried about accessibility I'd suggest using only allowed content inside the buttons. From MDN docs: **Permitted content:** *"[Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content) but there must be no [Interactive content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#interactive_content)"*

Comment: Can't change the code due to some issues. Tha thing is can I overpass screen reader that it does not narrate as a button for the section, label tags. But it should be able to read the content inside the tags.

Comment: Well you can overwrite their [role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles) but if you are able to add the `role` attribute then you are also able to change to markup itself.